# Appended selection not send data in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Different select fields are coming through append function in different id.

Every select field has its own id and when I create this select append field I also append input field.

When the user selects an option form select drop down value will go to their own input field but the problem I am facing is the first appended dropdown sends data in input field but others are not sending. Below is my code.

```js
 function make_variants(obj){
   
    var allVals = [];
    
 $('#variant_selectpicker'+obj).each(function() {
  var found = jQuery.inArray($(this).val(), allVals);
        
  if (found < 0) {
   allVals.push($(this).val());
            
  } 
      });
 
 var data = allVals;
    
    $('#variant_unit'+obj).val(data);   
    
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name="variant_unit[]" id="variant_unit+'obj'" value="">

    <select name="" id="variant_selectpicker+'obj'" 
    onchange="make_variants('obj')" class="selectpicker variant_selectpicker" multiple="">
      <optgroup label="Weight" data-max-options="1">
         <option value="kg">2kg</option>
         <option value="5af1c381e2240">6 kg</option>
         <option value="5af1c390ce765">4 kg</option>
       </optgroup>
     </select>
```

Comment: anyone know jquery in this world so please answer.